# C# - Creating a recursive function to calculate the sum of a list. Is it possible using only the list as the only parameter?

Tags: c#, list, recursion

So in my attempt to start learning c# one challenge I've come across is to create a recursive function that will calculate the sum of a list. I'm wondering if it's possible to do this using a list as the only argument of the function? Or would I need to apply an index size as well to work through the list?

```
int addRecursively(List<int> numList)
{
    int total = numList[0];

    if (numList.Count > 1)
    {
        numList.RemoveAt(0);
        return total += addRecursively(numList); 
    }
    Console.WriteLine(total);
    return total;
}
List<int> numbers = new<List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

addRecursively(numbers); //returns only the last element of whichever list I enter.
```

I was hoping by assigning the total to the first index of the list before deleting the first index of the list that when passed into the next instance of the function the index of each element in the list would move down one, allowing me to get each value in the list and totalling them up. However using the function will only ever return the last element of whichever list of integers I enter.

My thought process came from arrays and the idea of the shift method on an array in JS, removing the first element and bringing the whole thing down.

Am I attempting something stupid here? Is there another similar method I should be using or would I be better off simply including a list size as another parameter?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Combine 2 elements of the list then remove one element from the list and repeat until one value - thats the total

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If I'm not misreading, your method does exactly what you want: it sums the elements in the list, it is recursive (which is of course not a useful thing for summing a list), and it only takes the list as argument. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Apologies I didn't enter my error. I've updated the code. The error is that whichever list I enter into the function it will only ever return the last element of that list rather than returning a sum of those elements

Comment: Ah now I got your "error": The method _returns_ the correct value. You have to check the **return value**, but you only output an intermediate value. Remove the `Console.WriteLine` from the method and output only the **result**: `Console.WriteLine(addRecursively(numbers));`.

Comment: Once you've fixed this, you should know that's it's not considered good practice for a method that sums a list to delete all the elements of that list in the process (to "mutate" it). You might want to look into creating new arrays to pass down, or even using span.

Comment: And something you have to learn as soon as you start to learn programming: **debugging**. You can set breakpoints and step through your running code, watching the variables change their values etc. This way you understand what the code exactly does and how it fails.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you want to learn recursive functions a real task that benefits from recursion would be more useful.

Comment: Thanks Rene! Big oversight on my part. And thanks Nathan i'll have another go at that now.

Comment: Do you know that this isn't the right approach for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

> So in my attempt to start learning c# one challenge I've come across is to create a recursive function that will calculate the sum of a list. I'm wondering if it's possible to do this using a list as the only argument of the function? Or would I need to apply an index size as well to work through the list?

That's a great exercise for a beginner. However, you would never, ever do this with a `List<int>` in a realistic program. First, because you'd simply call `.Sum()` on it. But that's a cop-out; someone had to write `Sum`, and that person could be you.

The reason you would never do this recursively is `List<T>` is not a recursive data structure. As you note, **every time you recurse there has to be something different**. If there is not something different then you have an unbounded recursion!

That means you have to change one of the arguments, either by mutating it, if it is a reference type, or passing a different argument. **Neither is correct in this case where the argument is a list**.

For a list, you never want to mutate the list, by removing items, say. **You don't own that list**.  The *caller* owns the list and it is rude to mutate it on them.  When I call your method to sum a list, I don't want the list to be emptied; I might want to use it for something else.

And for a list, you never want to pass a different list in a recursion because *constructing the new list from the old list is very expensive*.

(There is also the issue of deep recursion; presumably we wish to sum lists of more than a thousand numbers, but that will eat up all the stack space if you go with a recursive solution; C# is not a guaranteed-tail-recursive language like F# is. However, for learning purposes let's ignore this issue and assume we are dealing with only small lists.)

Since both of the techniques for avoiding unbounded recursions are inapplicable, you must not write recursive algorithms on `List<T>` (or, as you note, you must pass an auxiliary parameter such as an index, and that's the thing you change). But your exercise is still valid; we just have to make it a better exercise by asking "what would we have to change to make a list that is amenable to recursion?"

We need to change two things: (1) make the list immutable, and (2) make it a recursively defined data structure. If it is immutable then you cannot change the caller's data by accident; it's unchangeable. And if it is a recursively defined data structure then there is a natural way to do recursion on it that is cheap.

So this is your new exercise:

- An `ImmutableList` is either (1) empty, or (2) a single integer, called the "head", and an immutable list, called the "tail". Implement these in the manner of your choosing. (Abstract base class, interface implemented by multiple classes, single class that does the whole thing, whatever you think is best. Pay particular attention to the constructors.)
- `ImmutableList` has three public read-only properties: `bool IsEmpty`, `int Head` and `ImmutableList Tail`. Implement them.
- Now we can define `int Sum(ImmutableList)` as a recursive method: the base case is the sum of an empty list is zero; the inductive case is the sum of a non-empty list is the head plus the sum of the tail. Implement it; can you do it as a single line of code?

You will learn much more about C# and programming in a functional style with this exercise. Use iterative algorithms on `List<T>`, always; that is what it was designed for. Use recursion on data structures that are designed for recursion.

Bonus exercises:

- Write `Sum` as an extension method, so that you can call `myImmutableList.Sum()`.
- Sum is a special case of an operation called `Aggregate`. It returns an integer, and takes three parameters: an immutable list, an integer called the accumulator, and a `Func<int, int, int>`. If the list is empty, the result is the accumulator. Otherwise, the result is the recursion on the tail and calling the function on the head and the accumulator. Write a recursive `Aggregate`; if you've done it correctly then `int Sum(ImmutableList items) => Aggregate(items, 0, (acc, item) => acc + item);` should be a correct implementation of `Sum`.
- Genericize `ImmutableList` to `ImmutableList<T>`; genericize `Aggregate` to `Aggregate<T, R>` where `T` is the list element type and `R` is the accumulator type.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
int addRecursively(List<int> lst)
{
    if(lst.Count() == 0) return 0;

    return lst.Take(1).First() + addRecursively(lst.Skip(1).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one more example:

```
static public int RecursiveSum(List<int> ints)
{
    int nextIndex = 0;
    if(ints.Count == 0) 
        return 0;

    return ints[0] + RecursiveSum(ints.GetRange(++nextIndex, ints.Count - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are some ways to get the sum of integers in a list.

You don't need a recursive method, it spends more system resources when it isn't needed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int sum1 = numbers.Sum();
        int sum2 = GetSum2(numbers);
        int sum3 = GetSum3(numbers);
        int sum4 = GetSum4(numbers);
    }

    private static int GetSum2(List<int> numbers)
    {
        int total = 0;
        foreach (int number in numbers)
        {
            total += number;
        }
        return total;
    }

    private static int GetSum3(List<int> numbers)
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            total += numbers[i];
        }
        return total;
    }

    private static int GetSum4(List<int> numbers)
    {
        int total = 0;
        numbers.ForEach((number) =>
        {
            total += number;
        });
        return total;
    }
}
```